# Disabling VBA module after Save As function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

When the template is opened it runs an Auto_open module.

```
 Sub Auto_Open()

 SaveAsUserForm.Show

 End Sub
```

This then brings up a userform that says please save as and a Ok command button.

[image]

When Ok is clicked it runs this code.

```
Private Sub SaveAs_Click()

Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

If Not bFileSaveAs Then Unload Me

If bFileSaveAs Then    
    Dim x As Object
    Set x = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    x.Remove VBComponent:=x.Item("Auto_Open")

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

This deletes the Auto_Open module so the save as user form doesn't pop up in the new file that was just saved. But I only want it disabled if the save as function is used (both using the auto open module or in the file tab

I also need it so if the user cancels the box it will disable the save function completely and only allow save as. But if the save function is used it ask for a password, so i can edit the template.

So basically when the user opens the template he cant do or change anything unless he SaveAs first, Then once its Saved As and the file name changes it will disable the Auto_Open module so it doesn't ask to save as every time the new file is opened.

Comment: Have you considered checking the filename and path and only showing the message if it's the "oginial" path?  Or if you mark the template as "read only" then your users will always need to "save as"...

Comment: Marking it read as will ask them to enable macros, Simply need a statement that says `If file saved As Then remove the auto_open macro`   and    `if save function is used Then ask for password`

Comment: Some code here you could use: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/535724-how-open-save-dialog-box-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: I don't think that helps me any, I've actually used alot of that code with the other modules

Comment: Yes - my bad: did not read your code completely.  You're not checking the value of `bFileSaveAs` before deleting the code though ?

Comment: what do you mean checking the value?

Comment: `bFileSaveAs` will be False if the user cancels the "save as" dialog, and True if they actually use it to save the file.

Comment: So `If True Then Disable Unload Me`     `If False Then Unload Me`? Ok that fixes half the problem but if I cancel and use the save as in file tab it wont disable the auto open.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code at runtime. You can use the [ReplaceLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264478.aspx) method to replace the line calling `SaveAsUserForm.Show` with a comment:

```
Dim mdl As CodeModule
Set mdl = x.Item("Auto_Open")
mdl.ReplaceLine(3, "'SaveAsUserForm.Show")
```

Caveat: If the line number to replace ever changes, this code will overwrite the new line. I suggest finding the line number of the text in question, and then using `ReplaceLine` with that line number.

(This should be straightforward, but it isn't. Apparently, you have to get the [count of lines in the module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264494.aspx), read all the [lines in the module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264604.aspx) by passing in the count of lines, split the text by line, and find the line with the matching text.)

Comment: I have nothing to replace the Auto_Open module with, and its only job is to prompt the userform. I looked into using the `before save` but that would try to remove the Auto_Open every time someone saved the new file and it would error out because it already removed it the first time it SavedAs. This did work for another excel project so thank you for that!

Comment: @Duraholiday I don't mean to replace the entire module, just comment out the line that calls `SaveAsUserForm.Show`.